# Avg Sql Query Always Returns int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one column for `Farmer Names` and one column for `Town Names` in my table `TRY`.

I want to find `Average_Number_Of_Farmers_In_Each_Town`.

```
Select TownName ,AVG(num) 
FROM(Select TownName,Count(*) as num From try Group by TownName) a 
group by TownName;
```

But this query always returns `int` values. How can i get values in `float` too?

Comment: The second `group by TownName` seems useless. What exactly do you want to get? Can you add a few rows and the wanted output?

Comment: Do you want the average over all towns?

Comment: Don't know if it works on sql server 2008 like in oracle and mysql but maybe with `avg(num)+0.0`

Comment: Indeed if you are looking for Average_Number_Of_Farmers_In_Each_Town, this will be exactly the same as what I would call Number_Of_Farmers_In_Each_Town, since in each town there _is_ one _one_ number of farmers, hance the average is equal to that one number. Unless you want to represent your number of farmers as a `float`, in which case farming is more dangerous than I would have imagined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH [TRY]([Farmer Name], [Town Name])
AS
(
    SELECT N'Johny', N'Bucharest' UNION ALL 
    SELECT N'Miky',  N'Bucharest' UNION ALL 
    SELECT N'Kinky', N'Ploiesti'
)
SELECT  AVG(src.Cnt) AS Average
FROM
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*)*1.00 AS Cnt
    FROM    [TRY]
    GROUP BY [TRY].[Town Name]
) src
```

Results:

```
Average
--------
1.500000
```

Without `... *1.00` the result will be (!) 1 (`AVG(INT 2 , INT 1) -truncated-> INT 1`, see section [Return types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)).

Comment: Funny that OP writes "i want average number of farmers in each town .... not the over all average" and then marks the second answer that was given to calculate the overall average as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is always returning `int` *logically* because the average is not doing anything.  Both the inner and the outer queries are grouping by town name -- so there is one value for each average, and that average is the count.

If you are looking for the overall average, then something like:

```
Select AVG(cast(cnt as float)) 
FROM (Select TownName, Count(*) as cnt
      From try
      Group by TownName
     ) t
```

You can also do this without the subquery as:

```
select cast(count(*) as float) /count(distinct TownName)
from try;
```

EDIT:

The assumption was that each farmer in the town has one row in `try`.  Are you just trying to count the number of *distinct* farmers in each town?  Assuming you have a field like `FarmerName` that identifies a given farmer, that would be:

```
select TownName, count(distinct FarmerName)
from try
group by TownName;
```

Comment: In Town A, you have 5 farmers. What is the avarage number of farmers in Town A?